# Android application closed unexpectedly with parser exception

Tags: java, android

My application closed after move from a gps activity to browsing activy. Below is the error.

```
> com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper]
> Parser exception for C:\filepath\AndroidManifest.xml: Element type
> "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or
> "/>"
```

I found the cause on the namely:

> "*...an external jar was not being found.  I thought those would be
>   added into the workspace, and not called from their origin, e.g. from
>   \Downloads.  Apparently not.* "

Is there a solution or a hint to fix this?

The manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="coms.molaroute.mu"

    android:versionCode="1"

    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AlertWebsite"

            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".PlanJourney"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".SendAlert"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".GetLocation"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in your AndroidManifest.xml.  Check around where you define your Activities.  Post the file if you want SO readers to help you spot the error.

Comment: post your menifest file here.It seems to be related to syntax error.

Comment: in your manifest you are missing tag `>` or `/>`

Comment: ok but every tag is open and well closed

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error in Eclipse IDE.

- check the manifest-file for syntax errors
- clean your project (e.g. build->clean or delete /bin-folder)
- go to the project/package explorer
- right-click on the manifest-file
- **VALIDATE!**

Everything should be fine now.